# cannot authenticate with API 400 bad request

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to authenticate the user with API. I have implemented a method for login function

```
 login() {

this.key = this.credentials.username + ":" + this.credentials.password;
this.base64 = btoa(this.key)  //base64

this.url = encodeURI(this.base64);  //url

this.contentHeader = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Basic " + this.url);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(this.contentHeader)
  this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, null, { headers: this.contentHeader })
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res);
      console.log("success:" + res)
      res => this.authSuccess(res.id_token)

    }, (err) => {

      console.log("rejected");
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

}

I'm trying to concatenate username and password and then encoded to base64. again it encoded to URL and post with combining with the header. I'm getting authenticated properly with the postman correctly. but in the ionic app, it says bad request.

Comment: If you check in the developer tools network panel, does the header that's sent match the one you're sending in Postman?

Comment: yes i checked, both the headers are maching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a POST request using HTTP or HTTPClient, the second parameter is sent as the POST body. It seems in your code you're sending the Authorization not as a header, but as the POST body.

Change it to:

```
this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, null, {
    headers: HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Basic " + this.url)
  })
```

Comment: I change it to null but the same problem arise

Comment: @UdaraIndrajith Can you update your question with the latest code then please? I'll take a look. When you sent in Postman, what did you send in the body?

Comment: nothing in the body. only header with the username and the password